# How to make app display picture for 5 seconds before going back to camera?

Tags: java, android, image, camera

I'm making a camera app and basically I want the image taken by the user, to be displayed for 5 seconds before going back into camera mode.

This code makes it display a preview. But what would I write after it to make it stay for five seconds? 
Thanks!!

```
  @Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

  camera.startPreview();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `PreviewFragment` which has `ImageView` on which you'd display the `Bitmap` created from the byte array `data`. Load the fragment.

In `PreviewFragment`, once the fragment is loaded, in `onViewCreated()` method do this:

```
@Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            view.getHandler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(PreviewFragment.this).commit();
                }}, 5000);

        }
```

Make sure you follow guidelines for dealing with large Bitmaps to avoid `OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in a thread. run the thread for 5 seconds snd then stop like this:

```
private Thread mSplashThread;
private final static int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME = 5000;

mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        //Do your work
                        wait(SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, xxx.class);
                intent.putExtra("showTheme", true);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);   
                finish();
            }
        };
```